# How to check that first n elements of a list match a reference list in python 3.x?

Tags: python, list, comparison

What the most efficient way to compare a list to another in Python 3.x, making sure that the first n elements match their counterpart in the other list? Reference list would be static but lists to compare may not have the same number of elements.

```
list_reference = ['Apples','Bananas','Coconuts','grapefruits','limes']

# This would be valid (elements at index 0,1,2 match their counterpart in list 'list_reference')
list_1 = ['Apples','Bananas','Coconuts']

# This would be invalid (same number of elements but order is different)
list_2 = ['Apples','Coconuts','Bananas']

# This would be invalid (order is ok but list don't start with same element as 'list_reference'
list_3 = [ 'Bananas','Coconuts','grapefruits','limes']
```

Comment: `list_reference[:len(list_1)] == list_1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all` together with `zip`:

```py
all(x == y for x, y in zip(list_x, list_reference))
```

`all` will stop iterating once it hits a false element, hence not performing any superfluous comparisons beyond the first false one.